# How to insert a backslash (\) into a data frame column name?

Tags: r, dataframe

For display purposes, I am trying to insert one backslash (`\`) into a data frame column name.

If I simply insert the backslash (`'\'`), then for some reason it disappears from the column name:

```
x <- head(mtcars[ , 1:3])

names(x)[1] <- "back \ slash"
##backslash missing
names(x)[1]
# [1] "back  slash"
x
#                   back  slash cyl disp
# Mazda RX4                21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag            21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710               22.8   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive           21.4   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout        18.7   8  360
# Valiant                  18.1   6  225
```

If however I try to escape the backslash (`'\\'`), then I get *two* backslashes in the column name:

```
names(x)[1] <- "back \\ slash"
##two backslashes
names(x)[1]
# [1] "back \\ slash"
x
#                   back \\ slash cyl disp
# Mazda RX4                  21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag              21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710                 22.8   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive             21.4   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout          18.7   8  360
# Valiant                    18.1   6  225
```

How can I insert **one** backslash (`\`) into a data frame column name?

Comment: It is the escape, you can check wth `cat` i.e. `cat("back \\ slash")` and `nchar("\\")#
[1] 1`

Comment: The way R is printing the `data.frame` object on the console, it will do standard R escaping. That means: `\n`, `\r`, and `\t` are single backslashes, everything else that you might think is "escaped" will have two backslashes. While I find it frustrating, personally, there's not much you can do about it *easily*. You can override `base::print.data.frame` so that it forces the use of `cat` (since `cat("back \\ slash")` *shows* what you want). This is a hack I do not suggest for casual use. If you are changing this for a *report* (e.g., `knitr::kable`), then there may be other options.

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I do want to use this eventually in R Markdown (`knitr::kable`). What other approach can I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're intending to use this with `knitr::kable`, then try this:

```r
x <- mtcars[1:3,1:3]
x <- mtcars[1:4,1:3]
knitr::kable(x, col.names=replace(names(x), 1, "foo \\ bar"))
# |               | foo \ bar| cyl| disp|
# |:--------------|---------:|---:|----:|
# |Mazda RX4      |      21.0|   6|  160|
# |Mazda RX4 Wag  |      21.0|   6|  160|
# |Datsun 710     |      22.8|   4|  108|
# |Hornet 4 Drive |      21.4|   6|  258|
```

Comment: This seems to work ok in the console (as shown above), but for some reason when I compile to HTML or Word I still get a missing backslash (presumably it's not printed). Should this approach work for HTML or Word output as well?

Comment: add `escape=FALSE` option

Comment: Have you tried double-escaping it? Yes, try @AbdessabourMtk's suggestion ...

Comment: Double-escaping it worked, for both HTML and Word output. So `knitr::kable(x, col.names=replace(names(x), 1, "foo \\\\ bar"))`. (Adding `escape=FALSE` didn't seem to help.) Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour for `R` is to print the escape characters this happens even inside character vectors :

```r
c("sd\\sd")
#> [1] "sd\\sd"
nchar("sd\\sd") 
#> [1] 5
# "sd\\sd" is 6 character if you count the second backslash
# while cat prints the actual string
cat(c("sd\\sd"))
#> sd\sd
```